# Tridimensional sort string array PHP

Tags: php, arrays, sorting

I'm trying to order this multidimensional array, with no success. I need to sort ascending by `pub_obs` but keeping the main array order (AC, BA, ..). The indexes inside the main arrays (0, 1, 2, ..) can change but the `pub_id` have to be the same.

```
Array(
    [AC] => Array
        (
            [0] => Array
                (
                    [pub_id] => 1
                    [pub_obs] => c
                )
            [1] => Array
                (
                    [pub_id] => 3
                    [pub_obs] => a
                )
            [2] => Array
                (
                    [pub_id] => 4
                    [pub_obs] => c
                )
        )
    [BA] => Array
        (
            [0] => Array
                (
                    [pub_id] => 1
                    [pub_obs] => b
                )
            [1] => Array
                (
                    [pub_id] => 2
                    [pub_obs] => b
                )
            [2] => Array
                (
                    [pub_id] => 7
                    [pub_obs] => a
                )
        )
)
```

Somebody can help? Thanks!

**Edit**

I forgot to say about the PHP version, 5.2, but @fusion3k was quick! thanks for the answer dude and for everybody who helped too!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use a `foreach` with main array by reference, then `usort` fore each row:

```
foreach( $array as &$row )
{
    usort
    (
        $row,
        function( $a, $b )
        {
            return strcmp($a['pub_obs'], $b['pub_obs']);
        }
    );
}
```

Output:

```
Array
(
    [AC] => Array
        (
            [0] => Array
                (
                    [pub_id] => 3
                    [pub_obs] => a
                )

            [1] => Array
                (
                    [pub_id] => 4
                    [pub_obs] => c
                )

            [2] => Array
                (
                    [pub_id] => 1
                    [pub_obs] => c
                )

        )

    [BA] => Array
        (
            [0] => Array
                (
                    [pub_id] => 7
                    [pub_obs] => a
                )

            [1] => Array
                (
                    [pub_id] => 2
                    [pub_obs] => b
                )

            [2] => Array
                (
                    [pub_id] => 1
                    [pub_obs] => b
                )

        )

)
```

Using references in the foreach the `usort` function act directly on main array, then in custom function compare `pub_id` keys to define nested sort order.

#### Edit:

The above method works, as requested in the question. However, if we have a sub-array like this one:

```
[
    [ 'pub_id' => 1, 'pub_obs' => 'b' ],
    [ 'pub_id' => 2, 'pub_obs' => 'b' ],
    [ 'pub_id' => 3, 'pub_obs' => 'a' ]
]
```

the output is:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [pub_id] => 3
            [pub_obs] => a
        )
    [1] => Array
        (
            [pub_id] => 2
            [pub_obs] => b
        )
    [2] => Array
        (
            [pub_id] => 1
            [pub_obs] => b
        )
)
```

The requested keys are correctly sorted, but — on same `pub_obs` value — `pub_id` order is not maintained.

To avoid this, you have to sub-process even the `pub_id` key:

```
    usort
    (
        $row,
        function( $a, $b )
        {

            $mainCmp = strcmp( $a['pub_obs'], $b['pub_obs'] );
            if( !$mainCmp )
            {
                return( strcmp( $a['pub_id'], $b['pub_id'] ) );
            }
            else return $mainCmp;
        }
    );
```

#### Using this solution in PHP < 5.3

Simply define a custom function with same content of above anonymous function:

```
function myCompare( $a, $b )
{

    $mainCmp = strcmp( $a['pub_obs'], $b['pub_obs'] );
    if( !$mainCmp )
    {
        return( strcmp( $a['pub_id'], $b['pub_id'] ) );
    }
    else 
    return $mainCmp;
}
```

and then call it inside the `foreach()` loop:

```
foreach( $array as &$row )
{
    usort( $row, 'myCompare' );
}
```

<kbd>**[demo](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/1f8a4f29c90dc4eef286aef7adb3c1917f43de68)**</kbd>

---

- See more about [usort()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.usort.php)

---

*PS: Thank you to @deceze for previous edit (maintained here).*

Comment: I agree with the [usort](http://php.net/manual/en/function.usort.php)! But your output looks exactly the same as his? What is sorted now?

Comment: You need to return a value `<0`, `0` or `>0` from the `usort` callback, not a boolean like the `>` operator returns.

Comment: I forgot one detail, the system is old, using PHP 5.2 (because I'll write another in Java), I tryed to do a callback in usort, but it doesn't work.

Comment: @HeliaquimCosta edited answer with 5.2 example and an additional note about a side behavior

Comment: @deceze Thank you for the edit! Edited again (maintained your opportune edit).

Comment: @fusion3k Perfect dude! It works! Thank you so much.

Answer (score -1):

You can use the aasort from this answer:
[Sort Multi-dimensional Array by Value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2699086/sort-multi-dimensional-array-by-value)
and apply it to each array row:

```
function aasort (&$array, $key) {
    $sorter=array();
    $ret=array();
    reset($array);
    foreach ($array as $ii => $va) {
        $sorter[$ii]=$va[$key];
    }
    asort($sorter);
    foreach ($sorter as $ii => $va) {
        $ret[$ii]=$array[$ii];
    }
    $array=$ret;
}
 //Now your array
 foreach($array as $key => &$value){
   aasort($value,"pub_obs");
 }
```